# Determine the values of $a,b,c$ for which the function is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: continuity

> Determine the values of $a,b,c$ for which the function is continuous at $x=0$
>   $$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(a+1)x+sinx}{x} \qquad \text{if} \ x<0 \ ; \\ \\
> c \qquad\quad\qquad \text{if} \ x=0 \ ; \\ \\
> \frac{\sqrt{x+bx^2}-\sqrt{x}}{bx^{3/2}} \ \ \ \text{if} \ x>0 \ .
> \end{cases}
> $$

I tried to solve the problem like this:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(a+1)x+sinx}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{acosx}{x}+cosax +1$$
$$=2+a$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+bx^2}-\sqrt{x}}{bx^{3/2}}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}-1}{bx}$$
$$=?$$
***Can you help me solve this problem?***

Comment: For the last limit, this is just the definition of a derivative at $x=0$ where $g(x)=\sqrt{1+bx}$.

Comment: so what does it become?

Comment: Take the derivative and evaluate it at $x=0$, then multiply by $1/b$. What do you get?

Comment: i didnt understand your observation. can u elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}-1}{bx}=\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}-1}{bx}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}+1}{\sqrt{1+bx}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+bx}+1}$$

Comment: Okay the limit is 1/2 and how can i find b?

Comment: so how can i find b? 2+a=c=1/2 so where is b?

Comment: @chndn, I don't see any condition for $b$ except $x+bx^2\geq0$.